# git worktrees and vsc

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, git-worktree

so I've recently started using git work trees and they are magical.

but when using with `vsc`, you will have the current branch name shown on the top (`my_branch`), so when you've opened more than 1 project (in my case I have 4 different projects interacting with each other) with the same branch name, you would get confused and have to browse the files to know which project you've opened.

is there a way I can show 2 levels of folder names, like `my_project.git/my_branch`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to edit VSCode's window title. Please correct me in comments if I am mistaken. The window title can be edited as follows

1. [Open `settings.json`, in either workspace or use scope](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings)
2. Add `"window.title": "${rootPath}${separator}${activeEditorMedium}"` and save the file. This will result in a rather long title, but AFAIK there is no pretty way to get just the parent folder's name into the title.

Available variables in the title are (copied from VSCode):

```
Window: Title
Controls the window title based on the active editor. Variables are substituted based on the context:

${activeEditorShort}: the file name (e.g. myFile.txt).
${activeEditorMedium}: the path of the file relative to the workspace folder (e.g. myFolder/myFileFolder/myFile.txt).
${activeEditorLong}: the full path of the file (e.g. /Users/Development/myFolder/myFileFolder/myFile.txt).
${activeFolderShort}: the name of the folder the file is contained in (e.g. myFileFolder).
${activeFolderMedium}: the path of the folder the file is contained in, relative to the workspace folder (e.g. myFolder/myFileFolder).
${activeFolderLong}: the full path of the folder the file is contained in (e.g. /Users/Development/myFolder/myFileFolder).
${folderName}: name of the workspace folder the file is contained in (e.g. myFolder).
${folderPath}: file path of the workspace folder the file is contained in (e.g. /Users/Development/myFolder).
${rootName}: name of the opened workspace or folder (e.g. myFolder or myWorkspace).
${rootPath}: file path of the opened workspace or folder (e.g. /Users/Development/myWorkspace).
${appName}: e.g. VS Code.
${remoteName}: e.g. SSH
${dirty}: an indicator for when the active editor has unsaved changes.
${separator}: a conditional separator (" - ") that only shows when surrounded by variables with values or static text.
```

Comment: That exactly is what I am looking for, thank you so much for this answer. Can you please also link the source page where you got this answer from so future visitors would get up to date info?

Comment: I actually left it out on purpose since the documentation lies inside VSCode itself - my answer was just worded badly. The documentation at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_is-variable-substitution-supported-in-user-and-workspace-settings was the only thing I could find regarding window.title, and there it is said to check the comments in the settings editor about the specific variables.